# applescript find and replace text in Illustrator

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get this applescript to find the placeholder text and replace it based on the return dialog. Maybe someone can see what I have wrong.

```
set OrderNumber to text returned of (display dialog "OrderNumber:" default answer "60000")
set CustomerPO to text returned of (display dialog "CustomerPO:" default answer "TBD")
set GarmentColor to text returned of (display dialog "GarmentColor" default answer "ASH GRAY")
set GarmentDescription to text returned of (display dialog "GarmentDescription" default answer "T-Shirt")
set DesignID to text returned of (display dialog "DesignID" default answer "TBD")
set DesignTitle to text returned of (display dialog "DesignTitle" default answer "TBD")
set Location to text returned of (display dialog "Location" default answer "TBD")
set InkColors1 to text returned of (display dialog "InkColors" default answer "WH")

tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
activate
end tell

on replace_chars(this_text, "AAA", OrderNumber)
{this_text, "BBB", CustomerPO}
{this_text, "CCC", GarmentColor}
{this_text, "DDD", GarmentDescription}
{this_text, "EEE", DesignID}
{this_text, "FFF", DesignTitle}
{this_text, "GGG", Location}
{this_text, "HH", InkColors1}
t
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
set the item_list to every text item of this_text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
set this_text to the item_list as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
return this_text
end replace_chars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach is to add custom names to the text frames you're interested in. Just double-click on the item in AI's Layers palette, then type in the desired name. You can then set the text frame's content from AppleScript like this:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    tell document 1
        set contents of text of text frame "DesignTitle" to "New Text"
    end tell
end tell
```

If you've not already done so, you should also get yourself a copy of Adobe's [AI Scripting Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html). While a lot of the content is just a rehash of information already in AI's dictionary, it does provide some additional details along with example code.

Comment: Ok, that seems more straightforward. Thank you Very Much!!